# center align anchor text within a div

Tags: html, css

I searched for this, but found no solution.
I have an anchor with a text.

The height and width of the anchor are set by JS on DOM load
I need the text inside the anchor centered vertically and horizontally.

Followed many tutorials on centering elements. None of them worked.

Here is my html

```
<a href="#" class="wpsc_category_grid_item" title="Category1">
    <span>Category1</span>
</a>
```

And my CSS

```
.wpsc_category_grid_item {
    background: #000;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
}

.wpsc_category_grid_item span{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

I need these texts, vertically centered as well..

[image]

Comment: Vertically and horizontally centered on page or inside some other element?

Comment: Not centered in what browser? it shows up centered for me in Firefox and Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/fYpub/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAjBE/) with your code. It worked after I added

```
width: 100%;
height:100%;
```

to `.wpsc_category_grid_item`

Comment: Sometimes it just takes to ask to find a solution you have been looking for hours and it suddenly works, turns out the WP plugin was resetting `display` property of `wpsc_category_grid_item` from `table` to `block`. Fixed. Accepting the answer, thanks!